# Start Menu (Possible) Malfunction, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I've come across a slightly strange thing to do with Windows 10's start menu. Sometimes it doesn't open correctly when I click to open it. See the two pictures below. The first is the standard, and the second is the other one that occasionally appears.

[image: Normal]

[image: Abnormal]

To get back to the original one, I just close the start menu and reopen it. Note that it *does not* open in full screen, and I have checked and tablet mode *is not* on.

To clarify, **tablet mode is not on**. As pointed out in the comments, the first screenshot does make it look like tablet mode is on, but it is not: I simply clicked on the start menu and hit Alt-PrintScreen, which takes a snapshot of the current window, not the whole screen. The reason that I did this is that I'm currently on a dual-monitor set up, so if I hit PrintScreen as normal, then it takes a snapshot of both next to each other, and I'd then have to crop it down. If you look at the *second* screenshot, then you can see a different StackExchange question in the background, but it is not centralised on the start menu. This is because I have done the same thing with the Alt-PrintSreen. See end for an additional picture.

It's a bit of a weird one. To be honest, it's hardly the biggest of hassles just clicking off and clicking back on again. I was wondering if anyone else had come across this?

[image: Full screenshot]

[image: Update]

Comment: Let me clarify in the post, as that isn't actually correct, but I can see how you've made that mistake.

Comment: Alright.  Do you have the current display drivers installed?  Does this happen with certain applications running?  Does this happen if you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: It's a new laptop that I got quite recently - 8 months or so ago. I'm pretty sure I've got the latest nVidia drivers - I had to download updated ones because CUDA was out of data (it needed to be up-to-date for me to run Matlab computations on my GPU). I've just added another picture to the end... it shows what it's doing now.

Comment: Tell you what, when I'm back from work I'll give it the old restart, then I'll update this if it's still doing it. :)

Comment: This is a bug I've noticed too (and on machines with integrated graphics, so it's probably not your GPU).  I've reported it in the feedback app.  Actually, I reported it even before the RTM.  Supposedly there's a bugfix update coming this month.  Maybe it'll be fixed then.

Comment: It being a bug is entirely possible.  There are two major updates in the works, the update that will be released in August and Threshold 2 which is due before the end of the year.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's very helpful. I'll just put up with it until it's fixed! :)

Comment: From my incredibly small sample, I can make the very dubious claim that it seems to happy only/more when I've got an external monitor plugged in, and I'm accessing the start menu on that monitor (not the laptop's in-built display).

Comment: There are other similar bugs, too.  For instance, with my Surface connected to an external monitor, if I click Start on the built-in screen, then immediately click Start on the external screen, a blurred slice of what's displaying on the external screen briefly appears where Start was on the built-in screen.

Comment: Huh, how weird. I guess there will always be various bugs like this. This is actually the first time I've had an operating system immediately as it came out, so normally these bugs are gone by the time I get there! Normally I just get a new OS when I buy a new laptop (that's how I got Vista and 8/8.1) and Windows 7 when I built my desktop.